# Gaussian Blur in Illustrator CC Problem

Tags: adobe-illustrator, blur

I am using Gaussian Blur in Illustrator CC. However, parts of the glow are outside of the line art. How can I delete those parts?

Before I applied the blur on that layer (solid color) i could easily delete parts of it, after the blur I cannot.

You can see in the image here -[image: pink circles] for example the blue hands - you can see part of the blur (shadow) outside the hand. I need to delete only that

Comment: Sounds like what you really should be using are gradients, not blurs. The blurs are working as intended and you can't just delete part of the blur.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a clipping mask.

Here I have 2 shapes. The bottom shape has the blur.

[image: guassian blur step 1]

Select both shapes and go to `Object -> Clipping Mask -> Make`

[image: Result]

In your case you would need to make a duplicate of the shape that will clip the blur layer.

Answer (score 1):

**Don't Use Gaussian Blur**.

If you want the blur to only occur *inward* on a shape, use `Effect > Stylize > Feather` rather than the Gaussian blur.

Gaussian blur takes the value you input and blurs half of it outward and half of it inward. It essentially blurs the edge of the object.

If you only want inward blurring, using the **Feather** effect does that. Just use *a smaller value* than you would use for Gaussian blur. Feather constrains the "blur" to the bounding path, ensuring no generated pixels go outside the original shape.

[image]

Comment: Hey, thanks a lot. I did the feather blur and yes, it doesn't blur out of the lineart. Honeslty, I prefer Gaussian blur better (for the looks of it), but I'll go with whatever won't mess my project.

Comment: Now you aren't making sense. The question *specifically* asks how to prevent the blur from extending outward.. . now you comment that you *want* it to "blur out of the line art".  I'm afraid you'll *have* to pick one or the other.

Answer (score 0):

Not really sure why you're doing it this way at all but if this is how you want to do it than use a clipping mask to remove outer areas. **I'd use gradients instead**. Anyhow if you're set on this then here's your bottom hand thing:

Three pieces:

[image]

Align the two:

[image]

Select, right click, make clipping mask:

[image]

Position back in place:

[image]

**But really I'd probably use gradients instead of blurs.**